# Determine record in multi record html form

Tags: python, html, cgi

In a html form, I'm displaying multiple records from a table, ready for update.

Right now I use: `name=<column-name>_<pk-id> value=<value>` for the fields.
Then in my python-script I go for:

```
for key in form.keys():
    if key.startswith('<name-A>_'):
        update <table> set <name-A> = <value> where pk=<pk-id>
    if key.startswith('<name-B>_'):
        update <table> set <name-B> = <value> where pk=<pk-id>
```

Is there a more 'organic' way to handle multi-record forms?

Comment: Which framework are you using? Are you using any ORM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like SQLAlchemy? If you are using an ORM (or willing to),then assuming the HTML is rendered from a python controller, the update of records has a much easier way.

Answer (score 1):

In java apps, it's common to JSONify the name.

```
<input name="records[pk].fieldName"/>
```

`pk` being the primary key of the row and `fieldName` the field. Of course most frameworks handle this transparently. Each record ends up as a instance of a class with a property for each field, all of which are put into a list called "records". You may have to write some sort of interpreter, but that shouldn't be too hard.